# Place files outside server root

Tags: file, server-side

When people say to place sensitive files (such as database config files) outside the server root, is that outside public_html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

If the file are in `public_html` and not correctly protected, they can easily be accessed by typing the url leading to them.

If they are outside of `public_html`, they can't be accessed from the internet.